# how to pass in a reference variable into a RenderPartial?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor

I am trying to pass a modelclass store to a RenderPartial. The goal for the renderpartial is to change/set values on this (store)model. I have been trying like this:

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("test", new store(){Output=""}); }
@{ Html.RenderPartial("test", new store(){Output2=""}); }


public class store
    {
        public string Output { get; set; }
        public string Output2 { get; set; }
    }
```

the  Partial 'test' has to change the Output properties. Is it uberhaupt possible and if yes how to do this? The renderpartial contains a javascript to calculate the value of the properties.

Comment: Why not use `Html.Partial` instead?

Comment: @Eranga, RenderPartial has a performance advantage in some cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RenderPartial is meant to get either none of the data from the parent or a part of the model.
The overloads at: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.renderpartialextensions.renderpartial(v=vs.108).aspx
Tell you object isn't a custom object but meant to be part of the Model, ex Model.Customers

Pass the required value from your model to the partial and let the partial create it's own objects.

If you really want to pass it to the partial then create a new view model for your parent view and set the Output property in your viewmodel and pass it to the partial.

Note also that the partial gets it's own copy of the data and cannot update the parents copy so that may defeat what you actually want here.

If you need some other calculate data do it in your controller prior to passing it to the view if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
@store st = new store(){Output="", Output2=""};
@{ Html.RenderPartial("test", new RouteValueDictionary {{"output", st.Output}, {"output2", st.Output2}}); }
```